# How to get value of input button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to javascript so sorry if this isn't technical.

I have an html

```
 <button type="button" id="btnlocation" value="chicken">Click me</button>
```

So i am trying to pass the string value "chicken" into the button click function

```
$('#btnlocation').click(function (value) {

  alert(value);  // This should output chicken 


}
```

But instead it outputs [Object],[Object] so how do i get the value or convert it into string?

thank you

Comment: click will pass window.event parameter to the function. you can access button value with this.value inside that function.

Comment: The two answers here are great, one thing I just wanted to let you know: java & javascript are 2 very different languages. One is a scripter used to power webpages and the other is a (relatively) lower level, cross platform OOP language.  In the question body you say java, so I wanted to make sure you knew!

Comment: Thank you for the information, I did not know that those were two different languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [first argument in callback refers to `event` object](https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-handler). For getting the value either use **[`this.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)** or **[`$(thid).val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/)** where `this` refers to the dom object of clicked element.

```
$('#btnlocation').click(function () {
  alert(this.value);
  // or
  alert($(this).val());  
})
```

```js
$('#btnlocation').click(function() {
  console.log(this.value);
  // or
  console.log($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btnlocation" value="chicken">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use `this`

```
$('#btnlocation').click(function () {

  alert($(this).val());  // This should output chicken 


});
```

Answer (score 0):

for getting the value use $(this).val() for getting the id of the button use 
$(this).attr("id")

```
  $('#btnlocation').click(function () {


      alert($(this).val()); // this is used get the value

      alert( $(this).attr("id")); // this is used to get the id of the button

    });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnlocation').click(function(){
        alert($('#btnlocation').val());
    });
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: added some explaination to my answer

Answer (score 0):

It is ideal to pass the event it self to the on event method.
From that event you can get whatever value you want of that element.

You can change you JavaScript as below to do so:

```
$('#btnlocation').click(function (e) {

 alert(e.target.value);  // This should output chicken 


});
```